# Populate an unmapped property of domain object from result of join with Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I have a situation where I have 3 tables: StockItem, Office and StockItemPrice.  The price for each StockItem can be different for each Office.

```
StockItem(
  ID
  Name
)

Office(
  ID
  Name
)

StockItemPrice(
  ID
  StockItemID
  OfficeID
  Price
)
```

I've set up a schema with 2 many-to-one relations to link StockItem and Office.  So in my StockItem domain object I have a property:

```
IList<StockItemPrice> Prices;
```

which gets loaded with the price of the item for each office.  That's working fine.  Now I'm trying to get the price of an item for a single office.  I have the following Criteria query:

```
NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(persistentType)  
                 .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ID", id))  
                 .CreateAlias("Prices", "StockItemPrice")  
                 .Add(Restrictions.Eq("StockItemPrice.Office", office))  
                 .UniqueResult<StockItem>();
```

This appears to work fine as the SQL it generates is what I qould expect. However, I dont know if it populates `StockItem.Prices` with a single object correctly as as soon as I reference that property NHibernate performs a lazy load of all the office's prices.  Also, even if it does work, it feels really crufty having to access the price by using:

```
mystockitem.Prices[0].Price
```

What I would really like is to have a `Price` field on the StockItem object and have the price of the item put into that field by NHibernate.

I've tried adding `.CreateCriteria("Price", "StockItemPrice.Price")` and the same with CreateAlias, but I get the error

```
NHibernate.QueryException : could not resolve property: Price of: StockItem
```

which makes sense I guess as Price isn't a mapped property.

How would I adjust the query to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to remove the ID from StockItemPrice, you could better handle this by using a **map**.

Declare your Prices property as follows:

```
IDictionary<Office, decimal> Prices { get; set; }
```

And map it like this:

```
<map name="Prices" lazy="extra">
  <key column="StockItemID" />
  <map-key-many-to-many class="Office" column="OfficeId"/>
  <element type="Decimal" column="Price"/>
</map>
```

Pay special attention to the `lazy="extra"` attribute. It means when you do this:

```
decimal priceInNY = item.Prices[nyOffice];
```

Only the price for `nyOffice` (an Office instance or proxy) will be retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the prices for all the offices in the `Prices` property, why go back to the database?

```
public virtual StockItemPrice GetPriceForOffice(Office office)
{
    return Prices
        .Where(p => o.Office.Equals(office))
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Typically I'll only ever need to show the data for a single office at a time (its an online ordering platform offices can get stock from). I guess that if NHibernate keeps the data in it's cache then that wouldn't be too bad.  But I wouldn't want to be bringing back all price data for all offices and then iterating through to get the price I want each time a page loads.